# The -kute (くて) form

Tags: conjugations, て-form

I have trouble understanding this form, for example why do people use "じゃなくて"?

Can you please give me examples?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Your question is a bit vague. Can you give an example sentence where you are having problems, and explain your problem?

Answer (score 2):

じゃなくて is how you use じゃない when connecting two sentences. Just like the て form of the verbs. So for example, if you want to say that you're not chinese and you can't speak chinese, then you could phrase it like 
中国人じゃなくて、中国語ができません
You could also add も at the end to express "even though". So
中国人じゃなくても、中国語ができます
means "even though I'm not chinese, I can speak chinese".

Comment: This answer is good, but I'm not sure that it answers the asker's original question of how the -くて form is used, referring to one specific example.